# Initialize database item template using values from the item in Notion

Tags: notion

I would like to create a 1:1 meeting notes template. I have a "Meetings database which has a field called "participants", I also have a "Tasks" database which has a field called "people". These are both a relation type fields for the same database called "People".

```
Tasks ---> People <--- Meetings
```

I would like to create a new template in the "Meetings" database which includes a "Tasks" table view which filters the "participants" field to match the "people" field in the enclosing "Meetings" item.

Is this possible?